Should I use ChatGPT to create cover letter for assistant professor jobs in math?
I am in the job market this year for tenure-track positions.
I was wondering if you could tell me how good/bad it is to create cover letters using ChatGPT. I am making edits after I generate my cover letter, but I am worried that my applications are not getting picked up because of AI-generated cover letters.
What kind of impressions hiring committee get after looking at such a letter? I am in Math.

Why are you doing this?


What kind of impressions hiring committee get after looking at such a letter? I am in Math.

For me, the effect would be similar to you writing
I AM A PERSON WHO LIKES TO TAKE SHORTCUTS
in big bold letters in your cover letter. Given that this is the sort of person you are, I would know that if my department hired you, we should fully expect you to continue to use AI assistance to write your course syllabi, committee reports, grant proposals, emails, and many other types of work products.
My likely reaction would be to be grateful to you for disclosing so clearly what kind of a person you are, and for saving me the work of reading the rest of your application and thinking how I should rate it.

Whoa, bit harsh. Accurate though. Worth an upvote, anyway.

Is taking shortcuts really that bad? Why is adapting to AI seen as a bad thing? Have you never taken any shortcuts? If the syllabus or curriculum can be generated using AI and addresses everything that a student or the coordinator needs to know , then what is the problem? Moreover, isn't that one of the purposes of using AI? It helps us to save some time and be more efficient? And, if English is not my first language, then why is it wrong for me to use AI to help me with the grammar and write more coherent sentences, and convey my thoughts more clearly?

@It'sMe, why hire a human at all, if the AI can do everything just as well?

@It'sMe Those are a lot of big ifs that nobody has shown to be true.

@It'sMe I would classify AI use into responsible and irresponsible use. Responsible AI use is where you put a lot of thought into writing a document but use the AI to improve your writing quality and/or overcome language deficiencies. That’s fine and is not what I would call taking a shortcut. Irresponsible use is where you try to dishonestly create a superficial impression (which invariably collapses under minimal scrutiny) that you put a lot of thought into writing something, when you actually didn’t. That’s what I call taking a shortcut. And yes, it’s bad.

@It'sMe also: if taking shortcuts is not bad, then writing on your cover letter that you are a person who likes to take shortcuts should also be not bad. Right? Well, feel free to write that in your cover letters and see where that attitude gets you…

"I AM A PERSON WHO LIKES TO TAKE SHORTCUTS" What is wrong with that? This says that I am a person looking for innovations and ways to optimize my work. I see this as a positive trait.

@pabouk-Ukrainestaystrong "my work" -- this is a problem. In academia, a lot of work is shared work (writing papers, grants, designing teaching approaches). When one team member takes shortcuts, the quality often struggles, and colleagues have to pull harder to have this paper published, the grant approved, classes delivered, etc.

@pabouk-Ukrainestaystrong Taking shortcuts can end in two ways. If one cares about their work, they may indeed optimise it to achieve the same results in an easier way. But the other possibility is that they take shortcuts to avoid any work, hoping nobody will notice. I dare say the latter is more common.

@pabouk-Ukrainestaystrong The reason it's called a shortcut is because the outcome has worse quality. It is fine to typewrite instead of manually write your course materials. That is not a shortcut. It is not fine to AI generate your course materials, and in general anything someone spends time to read in detail because AI does not produce anything at that level yet.

@PasserBy ok, it is my misunderstanding of the term "shortcut" in this context which comes from the fact that using AI for writing a text is not necessarily worse. The quality of the result strongly depends on the way you use the AI. --- 1. Cover letter is a course material. --- 2. Generating the base of the text in one go without enough input, using current AI, is worse. Going through multiple iterations with the AI and providing enough input could give better results (compared to writing without AI) if done wisely.

"You only get one chance to make a first impression" is a trite, but true proverb. And a cover letter is part of the first impression. By having a LLM do this - obviously important - task makes comes with a high risk that result is generic of lesser quality than if the time to write it themselves were to be invested, leading to the implication that this "shortcut" is not the "works smart to save unnecessary effort" but rather the "cuts corners to get things done faster" kind, and that the applicant does just this - cutting corners if they think they can get away with it.

"AI assistance to write your course syllabi, committee reports, grant proposals, emails, [...]" Is this necessarily a bad thing? I use chatGPT to write PHP code: it is not perfect, but it saves a lot of time for other, more valuable activities.

@JFabianMeier see my comment above about responsible vs irresponsible AI use. For coding, AI is definitely a timesaver and efficiency-booster. For letter-writing, my impression is AI use (of the “responsible” type) can help improve the quality of your writing a bit but only if you invest comparable amounts of time to what you’d need anyway to write your document. Alternatively, you can save time by using AI to write pleasant-sounding documents that are devoid of any meaningful content. If that is your goal, then I guess you too are a person who likes to take shortcuts.

@DanRomik you're really talking as if you have never taken any shortcuts. What about copy-paste? Would you count count that as shortcut? Have you never done that? When submitting an article to a journal, some journal give you two options- either directly submit your PDF file or submit all the files using their source file. Have you never directly submitted just the PDF file? Do you always sit and spend few hours converting everything into their source file?

Maybe the above two examples don't apply to you, but I find it hard to believe that you have never taken any shortcuts in your life or academic life. I'm sorry to say this.

Don't send emails either. Hand deliver the message/letter to the person. Earlier people used to mail the documents to the university. But now they just upload the PDF file and click the send button. They are not putting the effort of arranging the documents, sealing it in an envelope, writing the proper address and mailing it to the university. Why submit applications electronically? Why allow that? Ask the interested candidate to hand deliver the documents in you office.

@It'sMe I think there is a bit of misunderstanding here. DanRomik appears to talk about "responsible vs irresponsible AI use" and how responsibly using LLMs for this particular task is not a timesafer in their eyes as responsible use would require similar time for post-processing as performing the task "by hand" would and using it as a "shortcut" would require not spending the time for post-processing, making the use irresponsible.

Let me give a common example of my own regarding responsible vs irresponsible use of tools: Automated grammar- & spellchecking. Having potential mistakes highlighted makes all our lives a lot of easier, but - especially when "official" correspondence is concerned - should not be solely relied upon. It is a fine tool that will help us catch typos and similar issues, but it is inadvisable to simply assume "there are no red squiggly lines, everything is fine" and proceed to skip re-reading what one wrote.

@CharonX I agree with his comment about "responsible and irresponsible use of AI" that he clarifies later. But he doesn't give that clarification in the answer. His answer, especially the statement in big, bold letters, is expressing his dislike for taking shortcuts by using AI and it seems to suggest that he's going to judge/rate the application harshly. Also look at this second comment (the comment just after responsible and irresponsible use).

I feel like we're expressing a humanities vs. engineering divide here, and note that math is a humanities discipline, not an engineering one (even if engineers use math).  In the humanities, we care how beautifully something is done, not just that it works.  I haven't asked him, but imagine how Knuth (note the title of his magnum opus) would react to someone using AI to generate literate programs.  I think he would say it's besides the point.

As someone who recently read 20+ variations on pretty much the exact same cover letter for our department's open job, and was able to recapitulate almost that exact same cover letter by inputting a request to ChatGPT to make a cover letter for our job listing, I recommend against this.
ChatGPT is very good for "punching up" or proofreading a draft that you have already written, but left to create letters on its own usually results in pretty generic letters that will sound exactly like everyone else that requested ChatGPT write the letters for them. You want to stand out (in a good way) with your cover letter, and not blend in with everyone else.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

This seems like an unwise idea. Meaningless pablum, whether ChatGPT-generated or not, is distasteful to most mathematicians I know, and is unlikely to go unread.
In my experience at a US research university, pro forma letters that are brief and don't say much anything of substance are commonplace and fine; however, I've heard that at more teaching-oriented universities a tailored cover letter is very important.
If you do write a longer, tailored cover letter, then the purpose is to demonstrate that you've put some thought into the position and why it's a good fit for you. My guess is that ChatGPT-generated output is unlikely to convince anybody of this.

"the purpose is to demonstrate that you've put some thought into the position and why it's a good fit for you", I'd add that it is indeed a good idea to put some thought into why you think the position is a good fit. This can only be beneficial to the application process. And if the result is a well written cover letter: fine!

Hello, thank you for the answer. I am editing parts of it, but some words are generic and if I change with other synonym, it just gets weird sounding.

@Topology How would chat GPT produce a cover letter that explains why you in particular would be a good fit for that position in particular? Editing individual words to synonyms is not the point here, the point is that a LLM generated letter will be pointlessly generic. You need to think about what information you are conveying to the hiring committee about why YOU would be a good fit for their particular position.

If you use AI as a tool and carefully edit what it produces, then you should be fine. But, it depends on what your prompt to the AI was and what data it was trained on. If it produces generic text then it won't be very useful and might trigger readers that you aren't a serious contender. It might be obvious to some that it wasn't written by a human, even without a check.
I'd recommend against its use for producing cover letters (and other things), but only as a source of ideas. If I received a letter that I thought was AI generated, I'd certainly have doubts about the sender.
One normally writes a "generic" letter on their own and then tailors it for every application, based on the stated needs of an institution. You don't really need an AI for that, assuming you are applying to a reasonable number of positions. But the tailoring has to be sensible. If it is overly fawning or obsequious then it might be less than helpful, but more likely to be auto-generated.
And, if you aren't a native speaker, then an AI is especially dangerous to use as it may say things that aren't really proper, but that you don't "catch".

Hello @Buffy: Thank you so much for the detailed answer. I sometimes add specific details to my cover letter, generated by AI (where you ask AI to specifically pull out information from the job Ad etc). How does that sound? The only thing is: the language gets repetitive sometimes.

That "repetition" is exactly what you don't want.

I agree with this. There is nothing wrong in using AI or anything else, as long as the letter is of high quality.

It's worth remembering that identifying (or even suspecting) artificially-generated isn't that difficult once you know what you're looking for. To use it successfully, at the moment, for anything much more detailed—or nuanced—than a list or basic description, you'd need to adjust the language so much that you might as well have written it in the first place.
In other words, I suspect that using ChatGPT would either harm your approach or just not save you the time you might think it does.

(+1) For me at least (fortunately, a native English speaker), this is what I would expect happen if I did this. However, after having written an n'th draft, I suppose it wouldn't hurt to see what ChatGPT would write and see if it includes anything that I might have overlooked, in which case I'd proceed to write an (n+1)'th draft.

And once the AI-generated cover letter is detected, there's a decent chance it goes straight in the trash. Submitting an AI-generated application is basically saying, "Please use your limited time as a human to read my resume, even though I did not find it worthwhile to spend my limited time to write it." No, thank you.

identifying (or even suspecting) artificially-generated isn't that difficult once you know what you're looking for. - Can you provide a reference?  I thought with good prompting it can be hard to tell the difference.

It is likely rather disadvantageous for you to use LLMs to create your cover letter for you.
The hiring committee will use your cover letter (alongside the other information you submitted) to determine if you are a good candidate for the position. Using a LLM both obscures most of the information (as the LLM can and will - by nature - only generate generic text) while - should they notice that it was created by a LLM - make some likely negative implications about you instead.
If I were part of a hiring committee and notice an applicant submitted LLM generated content, I would need to assume that they don't take the job seriously, are likely to continue using LLMs to generate text for them, or (most likely) both - which would make them a very bad fit.
In short: It is a bad idea, you will leave a bad impression, don't do it.

Before I go on I note that the instant I started an answer, the message "Answers generated by artificial intelligence tools are not allowed on Academia Stack Exchange".  Bit of hint there, perhaps.
I had a job coach, years ago, who told that the cover letter is the most important part of the application.  It's the thing that stops your application being instantly binned (or shredded in more GDPR conscious places).
Every cover letter should be crafted and targeted at the specific role you want.
They won't even glance at your CV if they don't like the cover letter.
One day you'll be the poor sod going through a hundred or more of these and, trust me, AI generated crap will be dumped.
Writing a cover letter (which extends into things like looking for grant money for research and a hundred other things) is a vital skill.  Learn it.

+1 for the last paragraph, which makes a very good point no one else here has thought of making.

Chat-GTP can help with improving an existing draft. It says things things like 'you write this, can you give an example?' or it may suggest better wording (in particular for non-native speakers, it is really good at improving text in this way).
View it in the same way as giving the letter to a friend who may give some suggested improvements, but do not use it to generate a letter from scratch.

I'm maybe a bit more pro-LLM than some other perspectives. My feeling is that using an LLM to help you generate text is fine, but using it as a replacement for thought is not.
In other words, a good cover letter should explain why you are a good fit for the position. There is an implicit question here, that requires thought. Which of your qualifications match the description in the letter? What accomplishments do you have that will make you stand out from the crowd? What are your goals for your research and teaching? If all you do is prompt ChatGPT with "write me a cover letter," it will not know the answers to those questions, and it will show that you have put no thought into it.
However, if you have put in the legwork to have answers for those questions, then you can use a language model much more effectively than simply saying "write me a cover letter." You can write a much more specific prompt like, "Write a letter that talks about my  accomplishments X, Y, and Z, and that fits into University A which is looking for B, C, D. Make sure to emphasize my experience in super-duper-modern-technology and explain how it relates to Prof E's research in FGH." You could feed it a cover letter that you've written highlighting your skills and the job description and ask it to modify your cover letter to emphasize things in the job description. If you use it well, the result will be something that reflects the thought you have already put into answering the key questions for yourself.
Of course, once you get text from an LLM, you should not simply copy/paste it and call it done. You should read what it has written carefully, and use it for inspiration. Rewrite sentences to put them in your words (you may emphasize some ideas in a subtly different way), correct errors, add pieces that it has missed or that you have realized are important. In the end, you are still responsible for what you submit, and the text should reflect your thought and your work. But you can certainly use the LLM as an assistant to help you express your ideas.
On some level, the thought is the hard part, and coming up with text perhaps "should" be easy once you have done all that legwork. But you might have writer's block, or English may not be your first language, or just want some help since editing is often easier than starting with a blank page.

What I don't understand about this approach (as well as about many other uses cases of LLMs that people are talking about) is what's the benefit of it? The time consuming thing about writing anykind of non-trivial text is not typing a few paragraphs, it's (a) coming up with the right contents and (b) expressing those contents in a way that is most appropriate for the purpose and the audience of the text (due to (b) I disagree that coming up with the text were easy). How can an LLM save me a significant amount of time with those things?

@JochenGlueck For a cover letter I probably agree this is not going to help much. But, sometimes it is more time efficient or at least more pleasant for me to edit text than to start from a blank page. And I've also been able to use LLMs to take a "vomit draft" that contains the ideas but is too long and informal and make the text more concise, or to convert an outline into a first draft. I think if used properly it's just a tool, and like any tool there's a startup cost for using it that might not be worth it for everyone, and it's not the only way.

I agree that it's merely a tool. It's just that, with few exceptions, I haven't found the tool particularly useful so far, so I'm trying to understand what other people find useful about it. It might depend on one's personal working style, though. For instance, I would almost always prefer starting from a blank page over editing something that someone (or something) else has written.

(For the record: I'm not the one who downvoted.)

I'm not surprised this answer is controversial/downvoted, and lord knows I don't think I'm the source of truth and I could be wrong. But, I would say that LLMs are a big, new technology. One approach is to try to effectively ban a particular use case on moral grounds. Another is to try to accept that people will use the tools available to them and reward effective uses of it. We will see which one turns out to be more successful in the long term.

@Andrew 1) LLMs are not in fact "new technology". They're an overfed autocomplete. 2) Calling the objections "moral grounds" suggests that you've never actually paid even remote attention to what people who actually understand AI research are saying and why they're objecting to it. I hadn't downvoted your answer yet, but for that comment I am.
